# Does this group construction preserve finite presentability?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group. Consider the set $G^G$ of all functions $G \to G$, which forms a group under elementwise multiplication. Now, for all $g \in G$ let’s define $c_g \in G^G$ as the constant function $c_g(x) \equiv g$, and $id \in G^G$, as the identity map $id(x) = x$. Now, consider the subgroup $E(G) = \langle \{c_g | g \in G\} \cup \{id\} \rangle$.

$E(G)$ preserves several “finiteness” properties of $G$:

> If $G$ is finite then $E(G)$ is also finite.

*Proof*: $|E(G)| \leq |G^G| = |G|^{|G|}$

> If $G$ is finitely generated then $E(G)$ is also finitely generated.

*Proof*: If $A$ is a generating set of $G$, then $\{c_g | g \in A\} \cup \{id\}$ is a generating set of $E(G)$.

> If $G$ is residually finite then $E(G)$ is also residually finite.

*Proof*:  Consider the following class of maps $\pi_g: E(G) \to G, f \mapsto f(g)$ for all $g \in G$. All $\pi_g$ are homomorphisms and each non-trivial element of $E(G)$, maps to a non-zero element of $G$ under some of $\pi_g$. The rest follows from residual finiteness of $G$.

However, there is also a fourth “finiteness” property I am interested in but do not know how to deal with:

> If $G$ is finitely presented, does that mean that $E(G)$ is also finitely presented?

I suspect, it should be, but have no idea how to prove it.

[This question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4330034/407165)

Comment: Just as sort of a smell test: If $G=\langle x,y,z,w\mid [x,z]=[y,z]=[x,w]=[y,w]=1\rangle$ (so $G\cong F_2\times F_2$), then $E(G)$ satisfies $[[id,c_g],c_z]=1$ for every $g\in G$ (these square brackets are all commutators). Can these infinitely many relations really be boiled down to finitely many?....

Comment: Does “finitely approximated” mean “residually finite”, or “LEF”, or something else?

Comment: @HJRW, it seems, that this condition is actually called "residually finite" in English. It turned into "finitely approximated" as a result of an unsuccessful back translation. Now, I have corrected this.

Comment: @HJRW In any case since this group embeds into a power of $G$, this construction preserves both LEF and residually finite. And other residual properties (residually nilpotent, residually free, etc), approximation properties (sofic etc).

Comment: @MattZaremsky I don't understand. If you take $g = z$ and evaluate $[[\mathrm{id}, c_g], c_z]$ at $w$ you get $[[w,z],z]$, which is nontrivial. Maybe you mean for every $g \in \langle x, y\rangle$?

Comment: Well I think those relations do boil down to just $[[\textrm{id}, c_x], c_z] = [[\textrm{id}, c_y], c_z] = 1$.

Comment: Anyway for what it's worth $E(G)$ seems closely related to $G * \mathbf{Z}$. It's the quotient by the subgroup of "one-variable laws with constants"

Comment: I think $E(F_2 \times F_2) \cong F_3 \times F_3$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Oops, right, I should have said $g\in \langle x,y\rangle$, I think now it's right. I guess I still don't see why those relations using $g=x$ and $g=y$ imply all the others, but if someone declared to me that they were absolutely sure of this, I'd believe them. At least I can tell $E(F_2\times F_2)$ isn't $F_3\times F_3$: the former is generated by 5 elements and the latter isn't.

Comment: @MattZaremsky $\def\i{\mathrm{id}}$Since $c_z$ already commutes with $c_x$ and $c_y$, your relations are equivalent to $c_z$ commuting with $g^\i$ for $g\in\langle c_x,c_y\rangle$ (where $g^h=h^{-1}gh$). Since $-^\i$ is an automorphism, these things belong to $\langle c_x^\i,c_y^\i\rangle$; thus, since $C(c_z)$ is a subgroup, it is enough that $c_z$ commutes with $c_x^\i$ and $c_y^\i$.

Comment: @MattZaremsky Oh right, good point. I should have said that if $F_3 = F\{x,y,z\}$, $E(G)$ isomorphic to the subgroup of $F_3 \times F_3$ generated by $(x,1), (y,1), (1, x), (1,y), (z,z)$, but that's not quite as useful

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Aha, yes, that makes sense! So, I'd say now I officially have no idea what the answer to the original question is.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Are you certain that $E(F_2\times F_2)$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $F_3\times F_3$ generated by $(x,1),(y,1),(1,x),(1,y),(z,z)$? I think I might be able to prove that that subgroup is not fin. pres., but I want to make sure it really is isomorphic to $E(F_2\times F_2)$ before I try and think about it "for real".

Comment: @MattZaremsky I'm almost certain. Consider the map $F_3 \to E(F_2)$ defined by sending $x, y$ to the constants $c_x, c_y$ and sending $z$ to $\mathrm{id}$. I'm pretty sure this map is an isomorphism (equivalently, there is no identity $w(x, y, v) = 1$ holding for all $v \in F_2$). Assuming this, we have an isomorphism $F_3 \times F_3 \to E(F_2) \times E(F_2)$. The image of $(z, z)$ is $(\mathrm{id}, \mathrm{id}) = \mathrm{id}$, so the image of $\langle (x, 1), (y, 1), (1, x), (1, y), (z, z)\rangle$ is $E(F_2 \times F_2)$.

Comment: OK now I'm sure it's an iso. Given a putative identity $w(x, y, v)$, replacing $v$ with $x^Ny^N$ for $N$ large enough gives a nontrivial element of $F_2$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems the answer is no, $E(G)$ can fail to be finitely presented even if $G$ is finitely presented.

I claim that a counterexample is given by $G=F_2\times F_2$.

First, as @SeanEberhard explains in the comments, $E(F_2\times F_2)$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $H$ of $F_3\times F_3$ generated by $\{(x,1),(y,1),(1,x),(1,y),(z,z)\}$, where $\{x,y,z\}$ is a generating set for $F_3$. Now I claim that $H$ is not finitely presented.

First I claim that $H$ contains the commutator subgroup of $F_3\times F_3$. Any simple commutator in $F_3\times F_3$ is an ordered pair of simple commutators in $F_3$, so it suffices to show that any $(g,1)$ for $g$ a simple commutator in $F_3$ lies in $H$ (and by a parallel argument also $(1,g)$). This is easy to see because given any word in $(x,1),(y,1),(z,1)$ (and their inverses) representing an element of $[F_3,F_3]\times\{1\}$, we can replace each instance of $(z,1)$ with $(z,z)$ (and $(z^{-1},1)$ with $(z^{-1},z^{-1})$) and get a word representing the same element of $[F_3,F_3]\times\{1\}$ but now lying in $H$.

Now that we know $H$ contains the commutator subgroup, we can use the Bieri-Neumann-Strebel-Renz invariant $\Sigma^2(F_3\times F_3)$ to conclude that $H$ is not finitely presented. Indeed, $H$ lies in the kernel of the homomorphism $\chi\colon F_3\times F_3 \to \mathbb{Z}$ sending $(z,1)$ to $1$, $(1,z)$ to $-1$, and all of $(x,1),(y,1),(1,x),(1,y)$ to $0$ (I guess it actually equals this kernel), and the computation of $\Sigma^2(F_3\times F_3)$ (see, e.g., [Bux-Gonzalez](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024610799007991)) reveals that $[\chi]$ is not in $\Sigma^2(F_3\times F_3)$, since the "dead" edge from $(x,1)$ to $(1,x)$ in the defining flag complex has empty "living link". (Actually, I think $\Sigma^2(F_3\times F_3)$ is empty, so probably we didn't even need to isolate a particular $\chi$, and in fact every infinite index subgroup of $F_3\times F_3$ containing the commutator subgroup fails to be finitely presented, but I'll just leave this analysis as-is.)

---

Edit: By request and for the sake of being self-contained, here is the proof that $E(F_2\times F_2)\cong H$, compiled from @SeanEberhard's comments. Here $\{x,y,z\}$ is a free basis of $F_3$ and $H$ is the subgroup of $F_3\times F_3$ generated by $\{(x,1),(y,1),(1,x),(1,y),(z,z)\}$.

Let $\{a,b\}$ be a free basis of $F_2$. We have an epimorphism $\phi\colon F_3\to E(F_2)$ given by sending $x$ to $c_a$, $y$ to $c_b$, and $z$ to $id_{F_2}$, and we claim it is injective (hence an isomorphism). Indeed, given any non-empty reduced word in $c_a$, $c_b$, and $id_{F_2}$ (and their inverses) representing an element $f$ of $E(F_2)$, since $F_2$ is mixed identity-free, we can evaluate $f$ at some element of $F_2$ to get a non-trivial element of $F_2$, which means $f$ is a non-trivial element of $E(F_2)$. Hence $F_3 \cong E(F_2)$. This also shows $F_3\times F_3 \cong E(F_2)\times E(F_2)$. Let us identify $H$ with its isomorphic image in $E(F_2)\times E(F_2)$, generated by $\{(c_a,c_1),(c_b,c_1),(c_1,c_a),(c_1,c_b),(id_{F_2},id_{F_2})\}$.

Now consider the monomorphism $\psi \colon F_2^{F_2} \times F_2^{F_2} \to (F_2\times F_2)^{F_2\times F_2}$ given by sending $(f,g)$ to the function $f\times g$ defined by $(f\times g)(w,v):=(f(w),g(v))$. The restriction of $\psi$ to the subgroup $H$ is an isomorphism onto its image, which is generated by $c_{(a,1)}$, $c_{(b,1)}$, $c_{(1,a)}$, $c_{(1,b)}$, and $id_{F_2\times F_2}$, hence is $E(F_2\times F_2)$ as desired.

Comment: There’s a theorem of Baumslag and Roseblade that classifies the finitely presented subdirect products of free groups: IIRC they’re all finite index, which would confirm your final parenthetical remark. There’s also some relevant work of Bridson—Howie—Miller—Short, which relates the finiteness properties of subdirect products of free groups to the lower central series.

Comment: Sorry but for completeness it would be better to include an accurate proof that $E(F_2\times F_2)$ is isomorphic to $H$. I do buy the argument by @SeanEberhard but still it is sort of dispersed through several comments, so...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Good point, I added that.